# no module named OpenSSL

Tags: ios, ruby, set, pyopenssl

I try to get working SET on my iPhone for a week with no success. iPhone5S IOS 7.0.4

I try to do a credential harvester attack (site clone) but I always have the error message : No module named OpenSSL

OpenSSL is installed on my iPhone (with cydia). Nestat is also installed.
A lot of other tools : bigboss recommended tools, gcc, ruby 1.8.6...

The error message no module named OpenSSL appears just after the cloning phase where it should normally say waiting for connection something like that, the error :

```
Something went wrong, printing the error: No module named OpenSSL
netstat: option requires an argument -- p
Usage:  netstat [-AaLlnW] [-f address_family | -p protocol]
netstat [-gilns] [-f address_family]
netstat -i | -I interface [-w wait] [-abdgt]
netstat -s [-s] [-f address_family | -p protocol] [-w wait]
netstat -i | -I interface -s [-f address_family | -p protocol]
netstat -m [-m]
netstat -r [-Aaln] [-f address_family]
netstat -rs [-s]

netstat: option requires an argument -- p
Usage:  netstat [-AaLlnW] [-f address_family | -p protocol]
netstat [-gilns] [-f address_family]
netstat -i | -I interface [-w wait] [-abdgt]
netstat -s [-s] [-f address_family | -p protocol] [-w wait]
netstat -i | -I interface -s [-f address_family | -p protocol]
netstat -m [-m]
netstat -r [-Aaln] [-f address_family]
netstat -rs [-s]
```

I tried to install pyopenssl manually (not the one from Cydia) with no success :

```
/var/mobile/Downloads/pyOpenSSL-0.9 root# python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'OpenSSL.crypto' extension
/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.2.1 -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/usr/include/ -I/Users/linusyang/Documents/Code/python/python-for-ios/prelib/usr/include -arch armv6 -pipe -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/sw/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/crypto/crypto.c -o build/temp.darwin-10.5-arm-2.7/src/crypto/crypto.o
error: command '/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.2.1' terminated by signal 4
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

iOS (and OSX) developer tools does not ship with a OpenSSL library. If you need OpenSSL you will have to get the source and compile it yourself. In most cases the Apple supplied Common Crypto provides a solution.

The reason stated by Apple is because OpenSSL in many cases is not backward compatible to earlier, even recent, minor change versions. Thus a developer on compiling with a later version of an Apple supplied OpenSSL would have his code break. By not shipping the developer will have to select the version he uses and it will not change without warning and break the code. Theree were a substantial number of problems in this area. (This info was from a WWDC session a couple of years ago).

Comment: In fact, I just fix the no module named OpenSSL. but now, I have : 
No module named cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding

Comment: ok, I knew that. (Compile manually the sources). The question is how ?